# jersey. why doesn't parameter pass?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey

I have following jersey method:

```
    @POST
    @Path("path")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response isSellableOnline(@QueryParam("productCodes") final List<String> productCodes,
                                     @QueryParam("storeName") final String storeName,
                                     @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

          System.out.println(storeName);
          System.out.println(productCodes.size());
          ...
    }
```

in rest client I sends following data:
[image]

in console I see

> null 
>   0

What do I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `@FormParam` here?

Comment: You are missing `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`. Put it under `@Produces`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the parameters from query string, which go in the form:

```
http://yourserver/your/service?param1=foo&param2=bar
                              ^ start of query string
```

But you're sending the parameters as part of the form.

Change the way you consume the parameters in your service:

```
@POST
@Path("path")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response isSellableOnline(@FormParam("productCodes") final List<String> productCodes,
                                 @FormParam("storeName") final String storeName,
                                 @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

      System.out.println(storeName);
      System.out.println(productCodes.size());
      ...
}
```

Comment: Or change the way you send the params :)

Comment: @Narmer yes, but query string is not the main purpose for POST request, thus not offering that as solution.

Comment: Oh, missed it was a POST request. Yes, query params are for GET.

Comment: I got array with one element - I want to get array of three elemnts

Comment: @gstackoverflow instead of using a single variable with values separated by `&` just provide the same variable several times with the different values you want/need.